# Onclick event on jQuery dialog box not working with IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I am using IOS device and developing application. i face one issue with onclick event in  dialog box. I have one text box in dialog and need to call one function using onclick event. but it is not working in IOS(Ipad/IPhone). can someone check this and suggest me. below is the simple code which is not working in IOS. I have try ontouchstart event, that is working fine but what wrong with onclick ?

-code from Dialog box

```
<input type="text" onclick="hello();">
<script>
 function hello()
 {
    alert(2222);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Add the `cursor:pointer` style to your element see what comes up:

`<input type="text" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="hello();">`

Comment: @akazemis Thanks, but still it is not working in IOS,may be something goes wrong with IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ther is an issue with IOS  not registering click/touch events bound to elements added after DOM LOADS.
>
> IN you code to the below changes and it should work.

```
<input type="text" onclick="hello();" style="cursor:pointer">
```

> The above line will fix your code.
>
> Also you can refer the below link and know in depth as to why the IOS does not register click/touch events.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

> Hope this gives you a better understanding. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: Thanks, This code is working fine with simple page and IOS, but if i put it in Dialog box which is opened from the landing page then it is not firing click event.

Comment: @Mahendra Rathod if you dont mind can you share the structure here, i will be surely able to help you once i look at the dialog box. If possible?

Comment: @MahendraRathod also why dont you try implementing the below solution

Comment: I have try this solution also. but may be something goes wrong with dialog and event, so that again click event not firing.

Comment: @MahendraRathod just a suggestion, i hope you dont mind. Since you are using a Dialog, why dont you try binding the result of the dialog with the event.Result is going to be either true of false. Like the example i mentioned below?

Comment: @MahendraRathod Yes i will try creating this problem scenario in my environment , will surely let you know once i have it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am still working on it, if i get some solution for that then i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe alerts work for ios.

Comment: Also changing the cursor wont change anything other then the cursor.

Comment: alert is working fine with  IOS that i have checked.

Comment: @bugsiesegal Actually it is a funny workaround for IOS. Safari will not bind event listeners to "non-clickable" elements. So if a div is not clickable according to Safari, adding cursor: pointer to it will make the browser think it is a clickable element and then it will bind a listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML IS

```
<button id="demo" type="text" onclick="myFunction()" style="padding:10px;">
```

> JS is

```
function myFunction() {
            var x;
            if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
                x = "You pressed OK!";
            } 
            else {
                x = "You pressed Cancel!";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
```

> I checked it for IOS devices, iphone/ipad on chrome developer tool. It is working fine can you please confirm?

Comment: In chrome developer tool, my code is working fine with all device. but in actual device it is not working. and i am not able to place my code here.